# univocity - How to parse string from selected char

Tags: java, parsing, univocity

I have next .csv file:

> tt0102057, 6, 2010-06-19, Hook
>
> tt0102059, 7 ,2013-06-23, Hot Shots!
>
> tt0102070, 5, 2010-02-10, Hudson Hawk

I need to parse value from 1st column to the int value, not String. So i need to skip first two symbols and take the rest as integer.

How can I do this using univocity parser on the stage of parsing?

The code works and save data to beans:

```
    BeanListProcessor<univMovie> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<univMovie>(univMovie.class);
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    settings.setProcessor(rowProcessor);
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    parser.parse(new FileReader("src/main/resources/movie.csv"));
    List<univMovie> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options:

The easiest is to, on your `univMovie` class, add a `@Replace` annotation above the field that will receive that data:

```
@Parsed
@Replace(expression = "tt", replacement = "")
int yourField;
```

If your fields can be trickier and a regex is not going to be an easy/clear solution, you can put the `@Parsed` annotation on a method that will set that field for you:

```
@Parsed
void setYourField(String value){
    String cleanValue = someMethodToCleanYourValue(value);
    yourField = Integer.parseInt(cleanValue);
}
```

You can also tell the processor to convert multiple fields with:

```
rowProcessor.convertIndexes(Conversions.replace("tt", ""))
    .set(0); //one or more indexes
```

Hope this helps